# Is it possible to change the way DateTime.Now reacts in my solution by hard coding a date in the Web Config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need my solution to be processing on a specific date, but internal policy won't allow me to change the Server dates, hoping I could do this in the Web Config ?

Comment: Instead of getting the date with `DateTime.Now`, you could just do it by using the constructor to make a certain date, like `new DateTime(2014, 1, 18);` ? [See here for more](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime)

Comment: i think you need to add an example of what you want to happen on this...

Comment: Instead of getting the date with `DateTime date = DateTime.Now;`, which returns the current date,
he could declare it with `DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 18);` which return a DateTime-object representing 18. january, 2014 (in this case).

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` is .NET base class.

It doesn't knows anything about web.config existance and surely doesn't get any settings from it.

So answer is: no, you can't change `DateTime` behaviour by modifying your web.config.

Probably you shouldn't use `DateTime.Now` in this situation, and pass some date to your class/method if you want to change this date manually.

If you want to get this date from web.config, you add into `<appSettings>` section something like

```
<add key ="MyDate" value="20150702" />
```

And then just use some wrapper instead of `DateTime.Now`

```
public DateTime MyDate
{
    get 
    {
        var date = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["My_Date_Key"];
        return date == null ? DateTime.Now : 
                              DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMdd", 
                                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```